# Updating the Link of a page - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to edit this link via wordpress

```
http://domain-name.com/self-coaching-tips/media/
```

when I click on edit, I am able to edit the MEDIA part only. I want to update the whole link to

```
http://domain-name.com/media/
```

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add to your functions.php file:

```
function cstm_url_redirects() {
    $redirect_rules = array(
        array('old'=>'/self-coaching-tips/media/','new'=>'/media/'),
        //array('old'=>'/some-other-old/page/','new'=>'/some/new/page/'),
    );
    foreach( $redirect_rules as $rule ) :
        // if URL of request matches with the one from the array, then redirect
        if( urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $rule['old'] ) :
            wp_redirect( site_url( $rule['new']) , 301 );
            exit();
        endif;
    endforeach;
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'cstm_url_redirects');
```

More examples [here](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/change-specific-urls.html)